# PHP foreach -function-and calling a function for every 10 keys in the list

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$count=0;
foreach( $List AS $email){
$data  = my_function($url);
$count++;
if(filter_var($email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
...............
```

`my_function` runs a simple cURL for an url and returns `session_id` and `api_identity` as results. If I run it in the loop for each email in the list, my code is very slow and takes time to show results.

now

```
$data  = my_function($url);
```

Is applied for each email.

My question:

Is there any way to apply `$data  = my_function($url);` for every 10th mail in the whole list?

Comment: So, what is your actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, you want to do something every nth iteration, which can be accomplished using modulo operators:

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($List as $email)
{
    if ($count % 10 == 0) $data  = my_function($url);
    $count++;
    ...
}
```

If you don't know what `x % y` does, it simply returns the remainder of the expression x/y. A simple trick is therefore to use the fact that when evaluating `x % n` for different values `x = 1, 2, 3...`, the same result will repeat every nth time.

Note that depending on what your counter starts at, you will get a different start-email. If you keep it `0` as you have now, the function will be called for the 1st, 11th, 21st, .... emails. If you change it to `1` as I did, the first email for which the function will be called is the 10th one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/44883380/7095134 this answer or by using counter variable you can achieve that.

e.g:

```
counter=0;
for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
  if(counter==10){ counter=0; call_your_function(); }
  else {  do the rest of work; counter++ ;}

}
```